# What prevented Darth Maul from quenching his thirst for Jedi blood without Darth Sidious' permission?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace, darth-maul

We are well aware of how cruelly Darth Sidious abused Maul. The Sith apprentice was not a companion or a buddy to the Master, but rather a weapon forged by the dark side that would carry out his every command.

Knowing how anxious Maul was to kill the Jedi (to the point where Sidious threatened him with death if he continued to risk detection), what kept Maul from exacting vengeance upon the Jedi for the decimation of the Sith ranks without his master's permission? Was it devotion? own self-control? fear?

[image: Still image of Star Wars The Phantom Menace (1999)]

Comment: I imagine that "threatened him with death if he continued to risk detection" would indeed have had something to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In canon, Darth Maul did find a way to quench his thirst for Jedi blood without his master's permission. In the limited comic book run **[*Star Wars: Darth Maul*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Darth_Maul_(Marvel))**, set in the months before *The Phantom Menace*, Maul is not allowed to hunt Jedi yet, so he spends his time slaying criminals and low-level Force-sensitives, supposedly without Darth Sidious' knowledge.

He finds a Padawan, **Eldra Kaitis**, in the hands of the Xrexus Cartel, who plan on auctioning her off to the highest bidder. Although she was bought by a different criminal, Maul hires a team of bounty hunters to ambush him, leading to them crashing into the moon of Drazkel. To sate his anger and prevent the knowledge of his betrayal of his master from spreading, Maul kills Kaitis.

Afterwards, Sidious informs his apprentice that he orchestrated the events that led Maul to his first Jedi hunt, asking if it satiated his bloodlust. Killing the Padawan only made Maul angrier, so Sidious prepares a new mission for him: hunt the Jedi negotiating with the Trade Federation.